# LTSpice - How do we simulate pulses in RC circuits?

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I'm trying to simulate the circuit below, with values R = 2.2 kΩ and C = 47 μF.

[image]

My simulation is like this, but the results are not correct.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, can you explain the chosen parameters for the used tran specification?

Comment: @LvW Actually there is no logic behind them. I'm just want to see simulation between 
 that values .

Comment: No logic ? Sounds not too good....Recommendation: Find the time constant T=RC of the circuit and select a total simulation time of app. 10*T. The time step (resolution) should much, much smaller.

Comment: @LvW Thanks, I didn't know that, it's important.

Comment: Please show the plot for your simulation (after you have fixed the problems noted in the comments and answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to setup the pulse parameters properly.

The first parameter is initial voltage, this is usually 0 for a positive going pulse.

The second is the ON voltage, in your case it would be 20.

The third is delay time, this is 0 unless you want to delay the start of the pulses.

The forth and fifth are rise and fall times, make these some small value such as 1n for sharp pulse edges, or if you know the rise and fall times you want set them to that.

The sixth is ON time, for a square wave this will be half of your pulse period,  0.1666 for 3 Hz.

Seventh is the period, 0.333 for 3 Hz.

And the last one is the number of cycles, leave it blank for free running, or set it to some number if you want to limit the number of pulses.

When done yours should look something like this:

```
PULSE(0 20 0 1n 1n 0.1666 0.333)
```

If you want the pulse train to start high and go low you switch the first two parameters.

If you want something other than 50% duty cycle you need to adjust the ON time and period. For example if you use an ON time of 0.0833 with 0.333 period you get 3 Hz pulses with a 25% duty cycle.